# How to run Promise synchronously in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, promise

I have several methods in service that require third-party class instance which is initialized via Promise (see code below: `this.ready.resolve()`). To simplify code I want to put this initialization block in constructor.

```
import { DBReady } from './db';

export class SampleService {
    private db: baqend;
    private ready: DBReady;

    constructor(private envVariables: IEnvSettings) {
        this.ready = new DBReady(envVariables);
        this.ready.resolve().then(db => {
            this.db = db;
        });            
    }

    public method1(id: string): Promise<boolean> {
        // this.db must be initialized here
    }
}
```

How can I run code in constructor synchronously and get `this.db` instance initialized and accessible on request of `method1` ?

Comment: You can't, this is a limitation of JS. Async code cannot block the main thread. `method1` must itself await `this.ready` before accessing `this.db`.

Comment: Is there a way to simplify this code ? I just don't want to duplicate `this.ready` for every method in one class many times.

Comment: You need to create static factory in your class with promise returning

Comment: You can make it pretty clean by making an internal class method like `getDB()` which returns a promise for `baqend` then using `async/await` syntax your methods can just use `const db = await this.getDB()` and reference that local `db` in the function body.

Comment: Thank you Aaron, I'd proceed with your suggestion :) Just tested - works well.

Comment: Put the async stuff into another method.  Use a factory function that create the object and then returns a promise that resolves to the newly created object.  This is the standard way to deal with async stuff involved in creating the object.  This keeps the caller from using the object until it is properly asynchronously initialized.  Do not put async stuff in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

That doesnt look like a promise? Are you returning a deferred? And why are you resolving it yourself?

My suggestion is making the function return a real promise and the do await on that and marking the calling function as async. Ofcourse that isnt ok inside the constructor so you have to move that out into an init function.

A coolway to solve it is to make a @RequiresDb decoration that you place on the function using the Db, and making  it async. Then you just init the db there and cache the result

Comment: It's promise from SDK: https://www.baqend.com/guide/topics/getting-started/#connect-your-app-to-baqend. As I mentioned before Aaron's approach works for me. Thank you all for help.

Comment: Still if you end upp doing an await this.ready dance all over the place. Consider creating a decoration. It cleans up code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use factory method to async init what you want

```
export class SampleService {
    private constructor(private db: DB) {}

    static init(envVariables: IEnvSettings) {
        return new DBReady(IEnvSettings).resolve().then(db => {
            return new SampleService(db);
        });
    }

    public method1(id: string) {
        this.db;
    }
}

SampleService.init({}).then(service => {
    service.method1();
});

// or
var service = await SampleService.init({});
service.method1();
```